# jquery datatable - state save not working when removing/adding rows

Tags: jquery, datatable, state

I have a table that is using jQuery datatable version 1.10 ,

The rows represent questions and when a user clicks on the row it adds another row under it and opens it like a dropdown menu (like the accordion effect) and reveals the answer.

The problematic scenario is that you can open an close a bunch of rows and then do a regular search of any word in the search bar, the results are ok but the previousely opened rows are still open even thought the user closed them.
It is like Jquery remembers those rows that the user opened.

We dont want that, we want the results to come up with all the rows "closed"

I tried using bstateSave in the Datatable like this for example :

```
"bStateSave": true,
"fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
localStorage.setItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname,
JSON.stringify(oData));
},
"fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
var data = localStorage.getItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname);
return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

This is the code for removing and adding a rows on click:

```
$('.tbl tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
if (tr.hasClass("shown")) {
  tr.removeClass('shown');
  tr.next('tr').remove();
}
else if (tr.children().last().find('div').hasClass("ReplyData")) 
 {
    var answerString = tr.children().last().find('div').html();
    var row = table.row(tr);
    row.className = "openedReply";
    row.child(answerString).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
 }
 });
```

I tried adding this line to the upper code when removing a row but that also didnt help:

$('.tbl').DataTable().state.save();

I also tried reloading the table on the search event but no luck.

The cookies are saved on the page and i am using chrome.

Is there anything i am missing or any other ways of solving this would be highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable saveState function has nothing to do with what you are trying to do. SaveState is meant to store current page, search and order options between different requests, but no row content or styles. In fact, your problem has to do with table being redrawn when you search, so you loose the classes. You should store the row state in the data object of the table, and define specific render functions for rows or cells. See DataTable data and columnDefs.render.